# Downloading latest version of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, download

Can anybody tell me how to Download Qgis 2.2 new release version? In QGIS website they mentioned in download window QGIS 2.0 . if u checked released data it was 24 feb 2014.

So where i wll get QGIS 2.2 newly released version?

Comment: What OS? Linux, Windows, MacOs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see the old download window, for QGIS 2.0, because it is stored in your browser cache. Just `press the browser refresh button` and you'll see the newly QGIS 2.2 released version!

Answer (score 3):

Most if not all the major packages are available now on http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html.  Then refresh your browser to update the cache.

Comment: Version numbers 2.0 and 2.2.0-1 look very similar ;-)